# Having trouble with the data-amount accessing the value created in the charges controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have implemented stripe in my ruby on rails project in the way that there is multiple "offers" (different prices you can pick from ) on a "listing" page (a page displaying all the offers) So far I have it working in the backend in that when you pay for an offer it calculates the price correctly and the right amount of money goes to the backend.

The issue is that when the user checks out it doesn't show the value they are paying that goes to the backend. I believe its a scope issue where for some reason I can't bring the value across to the form page. Below I have the code as it is now.

Controllerfile.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :amount

  def self.create
    # Amount in cents. This amount will be charged.
    @amount = 0
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    listing_amount = @listing.amount
    @offers = @listing.offers
    @offers.each do |offer|
    offer_interest = offer.interest
    offer_month = offer.months
    @amount = (listing_amount * offer_interest * offer_month / 12).to_i
    end

end
```

stripe_form.html.erb The place it is getting it to show on the page is "data-amount="

```
<%= form_tag listing_offer_charges_path(@listing, @listing.offers) do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Interest: AU$</span>
      <%= @listing.interest_amount %>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="Purchase Book"
          data-amount="<%=@amount %>"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the amount in the `def self.create` method? 
Maybe you will set before the form are rendered?

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your application is not entirely clear, but since you are on stripe_form.html.erb I think there must be an intervening step between the controller and the view.  If you are using a redirect_to somewhere then it is possible that by the time you are getting the view, then @amount is empty. do @listing and @listing offers have valid values?